# Understanding the mechanics of P-adic topologies

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am trying to work out how it is that we actually work open sets on a p-adic topological space and how I would relate it to open sets in a point set topology. According wiki [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number): 
We have that open sets are of the form:
$U_a(n) = \{n + \lambda p^a : \lambda \in \mathbb{Z}_p\}$ where a is a non-negative integer and $n$ is an integer in $[1, p^a]$

Now I am trying to get the intuition of what is going on here. So say we take tuples of the form $U_a(n) = (p,a,n,\lambda)$ so letting $p= 3$ we get:
As $a \in \mathbb{N} n \in [1,3^a]$, and $\lambda \in [1,\mathbb{Z_3}]$ Varying first on $\lambda$, then on $n$ and then $a$:

$U_1(1) = \{(3,1,1,0),(3,1,1,1),(3,1,1,2)\} = \{1,4,7\}$
$U_1(2) = \{(3,1,2,0),(3,1,2,1),(3,1,2,2)\} = \{2,5,8\}$
$U_1(3) = \{(3,1,3,0),(3,1,3,1),(3,1,3,2)\} = \{3,6,9\}$

Then as all the terms are exhausted for $n$ we go to $a = 2 \Rightarrow n \in [1,3^2]$
$U_2(1) = \{(3,2,1,0),(3,2,1,1),(3,2,1,2)\} = \{1,10,19\}$
$U_2(2) = \{(3,2,2,0),(3,2,2,1),(3,2,2,2)\} = \{2,11,20\}$

...

$U_2(9) = \{(3,2,9,0),(3,2,9,1),(3,2,9,2)\} = \{9,18,27\}$

Then $a = 3$ and $n \in [1,3^3]$
etc.

So I see that for each $a$ we look at the columns at the above, these 3 - tuples as rows in a 3 by $n$ matrix we are covering all elements from 1 to $3^a$

So what? What do these sets of 3-tuples tell me and how is it that these $U_a(n)$ are open sets? What I am really interested in seeing how this topology (p-adic topology?) can satisfy the ultrametric.

Thanks for your insight,

Brian

Comment: I thought that the topology on $\Bbb Z_p$ was just that of the Cantor set, making $\Bbb Q_p$ being just a countable sum of Cantor sets.

Comment: Basically (this isn't a full answer), an element $m$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is "close" to another element $n$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ if their reduction modulo $p^k$ agrees for some large $k$ (ie. their representations in "base $p$" agree for a large amount of digits, starting from the right, eg $100000000$ is close to $200000000$). It's more or less reverse to what you see in $\mathbb{R}$ where two numbers are close when their representation in some base agree for a large number of digits starting from the left (eg. $0.000001$ is close to $0.000002$).

Comment: To get the curly braces, use `\{` and `\}`.

Comment: You’ve misinterpreted $\Bbb Z_p$: it’s not $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, which is how you seem to be interpreting it, but rather the set of $p$-adic integers, whose members can be thought of as the infinite sums $\sum_{k\ge 0}a_kp^k$ with all $a_k\in\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$. For $p=3$, then, $U_2(1)$ takes each $\sum_{k\ge 0}a_k3^k$, multiplies it by $3^2$ to get $\sum_{k\ge 2}a_{k-2}3^k$, and adds $1$.

Comment: I'm afraid I agree with Brian M. Scott's assessment that you have not yet understood what the $p$-adic integers are. To give you a first flavor with $p=3$ the set $U_1(1)$ contains all the ordinary integers that end with a $1$ in base $3$: $1_3$, $11_3$, $21_3$, $101_3$, $111_3$, $\ldots$ as well as the $3$-adic limits of Cauchy-sequences of such integers, e.g. $r=\ldots1111_3$. The sequence of $1$s extends to the left indefinitely. In fact we have
$$r=1+3+9+27+81+\cdots=\sum_{i=0}^\infty 3^i=\frac1{1-3}=-1/2$$ by the usual sum formula for a geometric series.